# LVM group disk usage

Tags: linux, lvm

My Server LVM group is report full disk usage.

```
[root@CH3CSSD01-0539 ~]#  pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdy2
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               464.24 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              118845
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          118845
  PV UUID               uV9hb7-eD2V-q6rB-KqP7-OJu2-J50e-LrETpH

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 1023:
    Logical volume      /dev/centos/swap
    Logical extents     0 to 1023
  Physical extent 1024 to 106044:
    Logical volume      /dev/centos/home
    Logical extents     0 to 105020
  Physical extent 106045 to 118844:
    Logical volume      /dev/centos/root
    Logical extents     0 to 12799
```

But actually disk is having lot of free space as seen by df.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  3.9G   47G   8% /
devtmpfs                  63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     63G   34M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                     63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdy1                494M  128M  367M  26% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home  411G  3.3G  407G   1% /home
```

I have rebooted host many times, still same. Can please help as what to do? I suspect its PE that are causing issue, how can i free up space on the volume group ?

Here is output of lvdisplay

```
[root@CH3CSSD01-0539 ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                5eHvlE-btOG-5bSw-Pvpa-YQgJ-DT5t-oo0OCb
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2014-09-04 23:48:10 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                NzUCNY-2Jd4-HAaM-juFu-Qy1n-sZ2Y-Nbxuh2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2014-09-04 23:48:11 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                410.24 GiB
  Current LE             105021
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centos/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centos
  LV UUID                1SjCaN-iwTR-MOdM-zzqc-QktM-sJSw-6JlVCE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2014-09-04 23:48:18 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1
```

Regards
AUn

Comment: Physical Extents is how much is allocated to a logical volume. How much space is available within the logical volume is shown by df.

Comment: I have added output of lvdisplay in my question

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is normal your Volume Group shows as full: you defined three Logical Volumes, which added sizes (50+410+4) match that of your Volume Group.

The rest seems in order.

Comment: 1% hardly seems "full" to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is perfectly normal.

Your Volume Group is full of Logical Volumes. Unless you need to create more volume groups, you don't need to do anything to free up Physical Extents.

Your Logical Volumes have file systems which then have free space which is what `df` is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

> Can please help as what to do? I suspect its PE that are causing issue, how can i free up space on the volume group ?

Until fairly recent versions all logical volumes are 'thickly' provisioned.  Even with recent versions I believe thick volumes is the default.  When I say thick, I mean that if you create a volume that is `410.24 GiB`, it will take up exactly that much storage on the physical volumes, even if that logical volume is completely empty.

Your `/dev/mapper/centos-root`, and `/dev/centos/home` seems to be extremely over-provisioned based on your current usage.  The simple answer is to shrink those filesystems, and logical volumes.  Hopefully the filesystems you have on this volumes are able to be shrunk, not all filesystems are.

Unfortunately, shrinking pretty much all filesystems is an operation that must be performed offline.  Also safely resizing things is a bit tricky.  Whatever you do, first start with making and **verifying you have a good backup**.

After verifying your backups, boot to livecd/liveusb that supports LVM.  Resize the  filesystem, then resize the logical volume.  There are many online guides about how to [shrink a filesystem+logical volume](https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+lvm+shrink) so I will not repeat that here.

For the future, I strongly suggest that when you create logical volumes, you use use the smallest size you actually need.  Increasing the size of volumes and filesystems is trivial and for most filesystems can be done online.  So make your lv/filesystem small, and just add more space as needed.